# Fibonacci Numbers Array & another copy of Array whose elements are divisible by 2 (Euler Prob 2), swapping out null elements

Tags: java, arrays, null, swap

This program finds Fibonacci numbers and another set of Fibonacci numbers that are divisible by 2.

PROBLEM WITH CODE: I'm unable to remove the 2nd array's elements, namely those that contain zeroes or null.

For example, the following sample output has zeroes that do not qualify as Fibinacci nos. that are divisible by 2 (i.e., under the call of the Euler 2 problem):

```
        Fib nos div by 2 except 0s: 
        0 2 0 0 8 0 0 34 0 0 144 0 0 610 0 0 2584 0 0 0

        The output should be:
        2 8 34 144 610 2584
```

And the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Fibonacci_Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int limit = 0;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            //number of elements to generate in a series
            System.out.println("Enter how many Fibonacci numbers to generate: " + "\n");

            limit = scan.nextInt(); 

            long[] series = new long[limit]; //contains all of the Fib nos. to limit specified. 

            //create first 2 series elements
            series[0] = 0;
            series[1] = 1;

            long[] divSeries = new long[series.length]; //contains Fib nos. divisible by 2.

            //create the Fibonacci series and store it in an array
            for(int i=2; i < limit; i++){

                    series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];
                    if ((series[i] % 2) == 0){
                        divSeries[i] = series[i];
                        //need to remove zero entries from the divSeries array.
                    }

            }

            //print the Fibonacci series numbers
            System.out.println("Fibonacci Series upto " + limit);
            for(int i=0; i< limit; i++){
                    System.out.print(series[i] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println(); 

            //print the Euler Problem 2 series numbers
            System.out.println("Fib nos div by 2 except 0s: ");
            for(int i=0; i< limit; i++){    
                System.out.print(divSeries[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to declare the divSeries as ArrayList to store the final result because of the unknown number of the Fibonacci number divisible by two.

So, the code will be:

```
 //Contain the Fibonacci number divisible by 2.

 List<Long> divSeries = new ArrayList<>();

 for(int i=2; i < limit; i++){
      series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];
      if ((series[i] % 2) == 0){ 
              divSeries.add(series[i]);
        }   
   }   

  //To print the result
  for(long i : divSeries)
        System.out.print(i + " ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different iterator for divseries

```
int j = 0; //for divseries    
for(int i=2; i < limit; i++){

   series[i] = series[i-1] + series[i-2];

   if ((series[i] % 2) == 0){
       divSeries[j] = series[i];
       j++;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't remove them, just ignore them:

```
for (long i : divSeries)
    if (i > 0) 
        System.out.print(i + " ");
```